# Got url to fetch json data with username and password, how to secure it as javascript source shows username and password

Tags: php, json, api, rest

(I am using json with PHP)

Hi i have got a url, from some web service saying:

http://www.example.com?username=$username&password=$password&fname=firstname

Now they said they i can get data with xml or json to retrieve data along with passing my username and password. And when i googled found json is better option. Now i hv done doing json and received the required data  successfully.

But i can see all the javascript i hav used to fetch in view-source of page. And so is the username with password.

I am a new programmer when it comes to use json or say fetching data with REST.

Can anyone just let me know the basic idea, that will be enough for me.

Comment: use `json_decode()` to convert json string to php array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do then is get that URL with PHP.  To do this, cURL is most commonly used:

```
$parameters = array(
    'username'=>$username,
    'password'=>$password,
    'fname'=>$fname
);
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com?' . http_build_query($parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

You should see the data from that URL with your code.  Now, since it is JSON, we need to decode that:

```
print_r(json_decode($output));
```

You should see a PHP object, where you can access its properties as needed.

Comment: Thats great...Brad i will user Curl for that. Thank you :)